# Подскажите пожалуйста, класный алгоритм на поиск минимальных циклов в орграфе, С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

Не могу никак придумать оптимальный, а можно вроде как за n^3 шагов.

Comment: Нужно сами пути искать, или их длину, или минимальный цикл в графе (а если их несколько)?

Comment: Последовательное умножение матрицы инцедентности

Comment: можете обьяснить в чем суть?

Answer (score 2):

Запускаешь алгоритм Флойда. Это n^3. Так находишь расстояние между всеми вершинам. 
Дальше для всех пар вершин считаешь сумму туда обратно. Это n^2. Так находишь 2 вершины, через которые проходит минимальный цикл. 
Потом с этих 2 верших вершин запускаешь bfs, который ищет путь в другую.

Comment: А разве из Флойда путь восстановить нельзя?

Comment: Можно модернизировать Флойда и запоминать для каждой пары вершин кроме длины ещё и промежуточную вершину. Мне больше 2 простых части (Флойд + bfs) нравится. На время влияет константа перед v^3. Модернизация Флойдуа увеличит её в полтора - два раза. Да и пишется bfs проще.

Comment: Ага, понял :) Интересная мысль.